# percentage widths breaking sticky div

Tags: jquery, html, css, sticky

I'm wanting to use the following layout with a sticky div - I'm using code from this example: [pixelbind - Make a DIV stick when you scroll](http://www.pixelbind.com/make-a-div-stick-when-you-scroll/#comments)

It works exactly as required when using fixed widths in pixels, however I need it to work with percentages, the left div 30% and the right 70%, but as soon as I do this it breaks the sticky div, particularly when resizing the window and scrolling again.

I can't seem to get it working & I'm not capable with JS. Any help much appreciated. Below is an example of it working with fixed widths:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var s = $("#sticker");
 var pos = s.position(); 
 var stickermax = $(document).outerHeight() - $("#catalogue").outerHeight() - s.outerHeight() - 0; //40 value is the total of the top and bottom margin
 $(window).scroll(function() {
  var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (windowpos >= pos.top && windowpos < stickermax) {
   s.attr("style", ""); //kill absolute positioning
   s.addClass("stick"); //stick it
  } else if (windowpos >= stickermax) {
   s.removeClass(); //un-stick
   s.css({position: "absolute", top: stickermax + "px"}); //set sticker right above the footer
   
  } else {
   s.removeClass(); //top of page
  }
 });
 //alert(stickermax); //uncomment to show max sticker postition value on doc.ready
});
```

```css
html, body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
body {
 font-family:Segoe UI, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
 color:#444444;
 line-height:18px;
}

div#wrapper {
 margin:0 auto;
 width:900px;
 background:#FFF;
 background-color:#0F3;
}

div#brand-detail {
 width:560px;
 padding:0px;
 float:right;
 background-color:#FFF;
 padding:20px;

}

div#brand-bio {
 width:230px;
 float:left;
 /*padding:20px;*/
 margin-left:30px;
}

.clear { 
 clear:both; 
}

div#sticker {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 background:#FC0;
 width:190px;
 padding:20px;
 /*margin:20px 0;*/
}

.stick {
 position:fixed;
 top:0px;
}

#catalogue {
 background:#999999;
 height:1000px;
 width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="brand-bio">
     <!--<h2>brand bio</h2>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum.</p>-->
        <div id="sticker">
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
            <p>stuff</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    
 <div id="brand-detail">
     <h1>Main Content</h1>
     <p>Here's some content, but that's not really important. The sidebar has a div a few lines down with an ID of &quot;sticker&quot;. Once this div gets to the top of the page, it will stick there. This is a great way to show advertisements without worrying that your audience may quickly scroll past them.  Could also play nicely as navigation helpers.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    
</div><!--/wrapper-->
<div id="catalogue">
       more stuff
            
</div>
```

Comment: What about this solution is "broken" and what's the desired outcome?

Comment: @André The solution works fine as i've posted it but I need to make the layout responsive, but when I try using % widths it breaks...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should only float the menu and relay on CSS position:sticky.

You may also use a min-width.

> some reading to help : https://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/ and https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-block-formatting-contexts-in-css/

Run the snippet in full page mode and resize window to see behavior, menu is 30% wide and at least 160px ..

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Segoe UI, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #444444;
  line-height: 18px;
}
div#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #FFF;
  background-color: #0F3;
}
div#brand-detail {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 20px;
}
div#brand-bio {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 160px;/* set any min-width */
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
div#sticker {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
  background: #FC0;
  padding: 20px;
}
#catalogue {
  background: #999999;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="brand-bio">
    <!--<h2>brand bio</h2>
        <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum.</p>-->
    <div id="sticker">
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
      <p>stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="brand-detail">
    <h1>Main Content</h1>
    <p>Here's some content, but that's not really important. The sidebar has a div a few lines down with an ID of &quot;sticker&quot;. Once this div gets to the top of the page, it will stick there. This is a great way to show advertisements without worrying
      that your audience may quickly scroll past them. Could also play nicely as navigation helpers.</p>
    <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium
      dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum
      magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
    <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium
      dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum
      magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
    <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium
      dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum
      magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
    <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium
      dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum
      magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
    <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium
      dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum
      magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
    <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium
      dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum
      magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
    <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium
      dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum
      magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
    <p>Fusce fringilla venenatis enim. Etiam vel risus vitae orci aliquet pharetra. Suspendisse vel eros a tortor ultrices luctus eget et ante. Integer nec odio ipsum. Duis eu felis ut elit cursus pellentesque. Etiam elementum eleifend molestie. Aenean pretium
      dolor sit amet massa iaculis ultrices congue mauris molestie. Aenean elit metus, facilisis non semper sed, lobortis eget mauris. Quisque molestie ultrices odio eget lobortis. Fusce a ultrices nulla. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed elementum
      magna lorem. Vestibulum arcu nibh, rutrum porttitor pretium at, laoreet sed mi. Integer eu lacus lorem, vitae euismod felis. Vivamus sit amet orci vel tortor adipiscing hendrerit vel id nunc.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
<!--/wrapper-->
<div id="catalogue">
  more stuff

</div>
```

Comment: thank you for this, I had wanted to use position:sticky but sadly I need a solution that is IE8 friendly and i don't think the there is a pollyfill for IE8. I should have mentioned that in the post!

Comment: @DavidBrookes  follow the link for polyfills, there will be different javascript options :)